# Confusion matrix plot with python

Tags: python, plotting, confusion-matrix

I'm for a function that can plot the following plot using python:

[image]

Comment: You can probably start from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py and add precision and recall as additional row and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer,

You can use [PyCM](https://github.com/sepandhaghighi/pycm) which is a python module in order to save your confusion matrix and its evaluation parameters in a html report.

You can use the following commands:

```
from pycm import *
y_actu = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2]
cm = ConfusionMatrix(y_actu, y_pred)
cm.save_html(filename,color=(100,50,250))
```

and the result will be as the following:
[image]